# Why would this function generate an http: 500 error on one of my files?

Tags: google-apps-script, http-status-code-500

I started getting this error in a lot more complicated script and after a while I tried this extremely simple case.  When I click the button I get the error: NetworkError: Connection failure due to HTTP 500
and of course I get the same thing in the console.  I've moved it to another file and the error goes away.

gs:

```
function runTwo() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('test'),'Title');
}

function getMessage() {
  return 'Hello World';
}
```

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id='msg1'></div>
    <input type="button" value="Click Me" onClick="iveBeenClick();" />
    <script>
    function iveBeenClick() {  
      google.script.run
      .withFailureHandler(msg=>{document.getElementById("msg1").innerHTML=msg;})
      .withSuccessHandler(msg=>{document.getElementById("msg1").innerHTML=msg;})
      .getMessage();
    }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

[image]

Just in case it matters,  this file has a webapp deployed that works with a Gmail Addon to delete unwanted emails. And here's that code:

```
function doGet(e) {
  Logger.log('query params: ' + Utilities.jsonStringify(e));
  if(e.queryString !=='')
  {  
    switch(e.parameter.mode){
      case 'dable':
        deleteAllBlackListedEmails2();
        return ContentService.createTextOutput("delete black list Done!!!!");
        break;
      case 'append':  
        const length=appendToBlackList({deletes:e.parameter.bls});
        return ContentService.createTextOutput(length);
        break;
      case 'length':
        return ContentService.createTextOutput(getBlackListLength());
        break;      
      default:
        return ContentService.createTextOutput("<h1>Unknown Command: " + e.parameter.mode);
    }
  }else{
    return ContentService.createTextOutput("No Query String");
  }
}
```

I'd like to know what the problem is.  But I don't know where to go from here.  I could certainly live without knowing and it doesn't seem to be affecting the performance of the other functions but it does impact my ability to built interactive tools for analyzing my data because I can't use google.script.run on any of my dialogs.  Anyway I thought I'd ask and see if anyone else might be able to get it to fail.

> **New Information**
> Problem went away when I removed a library that I just installed.  What should I looked for in that library?

> **The Fix**

Because I was unfamiliar with the new dialog I chose to use the head deployment and I really wanted version 31.  I don't know why this causes such an error but the script seems to be back to normal now.  I was lucky this time.

Comment: When I tested your script in your question, I confirmed that the dialog shows `Hello World` by clicking the button. So, for example, when you created new Spreadsheet and Google Apps Script and test your script again, what result will you obtain? Or, if you use new IDE, when you change the IDE to the old one and test it again, what result will you obtain?

Comment: Well thanks for taking a look at it. It fails in both the new and legacy.  It's something that has to do with the file that I just don't know about and I'd like to avoid having to move all the code to a new file.  On the other hand the other project I'm working on is designed to make that task a lot easier.  I was hoping that one of you might have suffered the same sort of problem in the past.

Comment: I can't reproduce it either @Cooper. I get "Hello World" using new IDE. Funny thing though, in the legacy IDE running on V8, I am not able to call `SpreadsheetApp.getUi()` from the context of the IDE, whereas in the new one I am able. Maybe the quickest solution for you is to migrate the Add-On to a new project

Comment: @Tanaike Any idea why a library  in head deployment would cause such a problem?

Comment: @Aerials Any idea why a library  in head deployment would cause such a problem?

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot still replicate your situation. By this, in the current stage, I still have no solution about this. I apologize for this.

Comment: If the library does not have at least a first version saved, it could be causing this issue in the new IDE. Make sure the library you are using has a version saved. You use the library HEAD, but it should have a saved version first.

Comment: Yes, the problem was that I had not selected the version because I was unfamiliar with the new dialog and after selecting the correct version  everything went back to normal.  Interestingly enough this issue also kept me from creating triggers.  It  kept telling me the code was not authenticated even though it was.  But it may have been taling about the library code.

Comment: Thanks for all your help on this.  As it turns out it was caused by a simple mistake.  I've been bouncing back and forth between the two editors lately and I guess I just got mixed up.

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to share with everyone a simple way to avoid the HTTP 500 problem described above.  It's fairly simple to reproduce and looking back upon it I can see now that it occurred because I was unfamiliar with the new editor and I made the simple error of not selecting a version.  Instead I left it the head deployments which is a problem.

This is my minimum complete verifiable example.

1. I created a simple library with only one function and I called it the HTTP500Library

The Function:

```
function selectColumnsSkipHeader() {
    var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sht=ss.getActiveSheet();
    var rng=sht.getActiveRange();
    var rngA= sht.getActiveRange().getA1Notation().split(':');
    var ul=rngA[0].replace(/\d+/,'');
    if(rng.getNumColumns()>1) {
      var lr=rngA[1].replace(/\d+/,'');
    }
    else {
      lr=ul;
    }
    var rngs=ul + rng.getRow() + ':' + lr;
    var outrng=sht.getRange(rngs);
    outrng.activate();
}
```

2. Then I deployed and actually due to a couple of stupid mistakes I have a couple of deployments
3. Then I created another spreadsheet called the HTTP500 Problem and I put this code into it:

Code.gs:

```
function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu('My Tools') 
  .addItem('Simple Dialog', 'runTwo')
  .addToUi();
}

function runTwo() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('problem'),'Title');
}

function getMessage() {
  return 'Hello World';
}
```

HTML:

function iveBeenClick() {  
      google.script.run
      .withFailureHandler(msg=>{document.getElementById("msg1").innerHTML=msg;})
      .withSuccessHandler(msg=>{document.getElementById("msg1").innerHTML=msg;})
      .getMessage();
    }

```
</html><!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id='msg1'></div>
    <input type="button" value="Click Me" onClick="iveBeenClick();" />
    <script>
    function iveBeenClick() {  
      google.script.run
      .withFailureHandler(msg=>{document.getElementById("msg1").innerHTML=msg;})
      .withSuccessHandler(msg=>{document.getElementById("msg1").innerHTML=msg;})
      .getMessage();
    }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

4. After setting up the problem I tested the dialog that I just created and it worked fine with no problems.
5. Then I added the library that I just created but  because I was unfamiliar with the new editor I mistakenly chose the head deployment. In other words I didn't select a version.
6. I ran the dialog again and this time I recieved the Network Connection problem with the  HTTP 500 error.
7. The next step should have been to realize that I didn't select the correct version and return to the dialog and do so and that would have fixed the problem.
8. So I guess the Network connection that cause the problem was the connection to the library.  So don't forget to pick the appropriate deploy of your libraries when you install them.

Thank for all the help